# Retrieve all the available color in product collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection, color-swatches, attribute-options

I have a custom `product collection` and products inside this collection has variety of colors. I want to retrieve all the colors available inside this `product collection` and store it in array.

```
$layer = $this->getLayer();
$productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
       'entity_id',
       ['in' => $querydata->getData()]
);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please update the code.

Comment: @padhiyargaurang see my updated question

Comment: Does it works??

Answer (score 0):

```
$layer = $this->getLayer();
$productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
   'entity_id',
   ['in' => $querydata->getData()]
);
```

Use below code:

```
$productCollection->getColumnValues('color'); // your field name
```